# problem of adding a QPushButton using setItemWidget inside QListWidgetItem

Tags: qt

I want to add a QPushButton inside ListItm, so I have implemented the code as given below. But the button comes in the middle of the list, actually I want it at the lower end of the list item. How is it possible. Also that button click event is not working. Actually I want to disable the item click event directly and by clicking the button inside the QListWidgetItem, I want to enable the item click event. But I am not able to perform this operation. How to do this? I have used the following code snippet:

```
list=new QListWidget(this);
// list->setStyleSheet("* { background-color:rgb(0,0,0); padding: 10px ; color:rgb(255,255,255)}");
list->setGeometry(0,61,360,475);
list->setSortingEnabled(true);
//connect(list,SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)),this,SLOT(ItemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)));

item=new QListWidgetItem();
item->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/Icon.png"));
item->setText("Item1");
item->setSizeHint(QSize(80,80));
item->setBackgroundColor(QColor(200,255,100));

list->addItem(item);
QPushButton *but = new QPushButton(">");
but->setMaximumSize(50,80);
but->setFlat(true);
// but->setGeometry(QRect(500,100,100,100));
but->setStyleSheet("background: transparent; border: none");
QHBoxLayout *layout= new QHBoxLayout();
layout->addWidget(but);
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
widget->setLayout(layout);
item->setSizeHint(widget->sizeHint());
list->setItemWidget(item, widget);
connect(but, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ItemClicked()));
#if defined(Q_WS_S60)
list->showMaximized();
#else
list->show();
#endif

ItemClicked()
{
int Index = list->currentIndex().row();//Always getting this Index as -1
}
```

Please have a look on the above code and provide your suggestions.
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Reconsider using QPushButton as "click" handle for listwidget. There is a reason why QListWidgetItem is not QObject. QObjects are somewhat "heavy", because of all metadata structures they hold. That's why Qt is not using QObjects in data oriented lists like QListWidgetItem.

About your problem. You will get always -1, until you won't select item by NOT clicking on it's button part, but on item. That's because QPushButton is taking focus away, and doesn't pass click event down to QListWidgetItem. So it may even happend, that you select item with idx = 3, click on button of item with idx = 1 and will get in your slot idx 3.

Actualy, as for me you're performing your whole taks totaly wrong. First of all, I would use QTreeWidget, for multicolumns. Secondly, I would "implement" custom item delegate, to draw "button", and I would set it as delegate for column 1. Then I would catch "click event" normally, but react only for column 1.

`| column 0 (actual data exposition) | column 1 (custom delegate, draw button)`